# How create a visible folder of Android application?

Tags: android, directory

I just tried to create a new application for android 4.4.4.

How can I create an application that is installed in the internal memory of the device and I can see some files (database,photo..) at path: my s5 phone/[my_package]/Database

Thanks

[image]

Comment: negative vote withoud reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I afraid you can't see any files on the internal memory of one device except you have the `root` permission. **You need to root your device**.

PS: Here is details about `internal and external storage`, have a check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363554/access-external-storage-in-file-chooser#29381424) if you are still interested.

Comment: So how i see now a WhatsApp folder at /internal/whatsApp

Comment: @user3428151 this is not an internal storage. What you see is on the disc storage. It is just like a u-disc which is just a storage device. Android system files is on internal storage which is not permitted to access except you have root permission. Just like the root account on you Linux/Unix system.

Comment: so what is the option to create the same "visible" folder li whatsapp?

that is not on external memory.
Thanks.

Comment: Just as I told you, root your device first. And then, install some file managers like `ES File Explorer` or `Root Explorer Pro`, you could check files which have root permission.

Comment: But if whatsapp can create visible folder that stores database on internal storage without root my device, why i cannot create such visible folder?

Comment: If Whatsapp create a database by using SQLite, you would can't see the database on the external storage. Anything about SQLite would be stored in `'/data/data/<app-package-name>/databases/<your-db-name>'`, could you see this directory? If not, stop talking about internal or external storage with me. Files created by using `Envionment` are stored in the external storage

Comment: I add a screen shot , this folder of a whatsapp application on my phone, i need to create same folder for my application, it is possible? my phone is not root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74086/discussion-between-silentknight-and-user3428151).