# Android KitKat sdcard write permission

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, sd-card, android-sdcard

In android KitKat there are some limitations for writing to SDcard.

So my question: Is it always permitted to write to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` even in KitKat?

Comment: No. With INTERNET permission requested in your manifest yes. The external storage you mention has nothing to do with an SD card though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it always permitted to write to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) even in KitKat?

If your app has requested the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, then yes, as `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` points to [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) ("SDCard") on the *vast* majority of devices.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand concepts of [Android Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363554/access-external-storage-in-file-chooser#29381424).
Then you will understand that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or something like that is about `primary external storage`. And it has nothing to do with `Android API`s whether it is younger or older than `KitKat`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the internal SD card you can use

```
String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
File f_exts = new File(extStore);
```

To get the external SD card you can use

```
String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
File f_secs = new File(secStore);
```

On running the code

```
 extStore = "/storage/emulated/legacy"
 secStore = "/storage/extSdCarcd"
```

works perfectly!

refer following Link , I think ur question has been answered already check this...

[Android Open External Storage directory(sdcard) for storing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file)

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work on all devices. Not even if they have kitkat.